# local data storage for a web app

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, file

I'm making a local web app to be used offline and need a way of 'saving' data locally and also being able to read it. I know javascript doesn't really allow for this except in a sandboxed way. What would be the best way to go about this.

Can I set up a local sever database to store and load the data?

The solution ideally needs to be cross browser compatible, so 'local storage' wouldn't be an option.

thanks

Comment: cookies :) Crossbrowser, work offline and everywhere

Comment: would work but too limited in size

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does allow for this...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Other domains cannot read your domains local storage.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned - it needs to be cross browser compatible, so local storage wouldn't work..

Comment: gotcha, yea, i think you'll need the server for that one

Comment: any ideas about how to go about that?

Comment: build an api to save the data and one to serve the data.   when the webapp starts load the data from the server and then save it to the server when it's relevant to your needs.

Comment: If this is solely for local use like a desktop app could u use electron instead of a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use html5 localstorage. Take a look at this link for more information [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

```
const someData = { 'a': 0, 'b': 1};

//add to local storage
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(someData));

// Retrieve from storage
const retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('data');
```

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned - it needs to be cross browser compatible, so local storage wouldn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You should check localStorage polyfill: https://github.com/mortzdk/localStorage

This polyfill uses Flash for old browsers and native localStorage for new browsers.